# Invalid regular expression: missing /

Tags: jquery, playframework, playframework-1.x

This is the piece of code that is throwing the error:

```
        <div align="right">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
                value="Confirm and Process Payroll"
                onclick="@{Payroll.confirmAttendance()}">
        </div>
```

which after compiling looks like

```
<div align="right">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
    value="Confirm and Process Payroll"
    onclick="/confirm">
</div>
```

Cannot seem to find out what is causing that error. I also use twitter bootstrap. Could there be a clash? This piece of code lies inside a jQuery accordion.

EDIT: However, if I change the input tag to an anchor tag, it works fine.

Comment: Is this Play 2? (`@` indicates that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick="/some-url"` doesn't make any sense for the JavaScript insted you should put there call to some JavaScript method ie: `onclick="processConfirmation()"`.

Of course you need to create and include that method.

```
<script>
    function processConfirmation(){
        // perform the action you want to here...
    }
</script>
```

What's more if you're using jQuery, you can also use its selectors and events for firing JS actions:

```
<input id="process-btn" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"
    value="Confirm and Process Payroll" />

<script>
    $("#process-btn").click(function(){
        // perform an action on every click on element with id="process-btn"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Correct. Thats where I went wrong. I think I need some sleep. I changed it to an anchor tag with a href, but I hate it when the cursor changes to the hand-thingy and the url is shown in the lower left corner.

Comment: @theTuxRacer - your users probably won't appreciate atypical link behavior, though.